# Merge multiple commits from my dev branch to my master branch?

Tags: git

I did the following in my git repository.

1. git commit my changes
2. create and checkout a dev branch
3. git make 3 commits to the dev branch

My question is how can I take the 3 commits from my dev branch and merge to my master branch and append to commit #1?

Comment: Checkout master, merge dev - yes? This sounds like a straightforward merge. Why would this be a difficulty? (I'm not carping, I'm wondering if there is something that you need to have explained.)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "append"?

Comment: I'm trying to elicit whether he knows what "commit" and "merge" mean... (And "branch")

Comment: Question is trivial, poster is unresponsive to questions, voting to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git checkout master` followed by `git merge dev`

Note that the above will take all the changes in dev branch and put them into master. If you just want those selective 3 commits which you did in dev branch then you need to use `git cherry-pick <commit_id>`. Lets say you have those 3 commits with commit id's as commit_id1, commit_id2 and commit_id3 with commit_id3 being the latest commit, you need to execute the following commands

1. git checkout master
2. git cherry-pick commit_id1
3. git cherry-pick commit_id2
4. git cherry-pick commit_id3

Comment: After I cherry-pick, how can I combine all of them into 1 commit?

Comment: you can use `git rebase -i origin/master`, it will open an interactive rebase window. You will need to study a bit about git rebase before you want to try it out on the actual working project

Comment: This example might help http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html